# C++ - is not a class or namespace error

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm getting the following error 'fw' is not a class or namespace in the main file when I try to call the create_event_file() function.

Here is my code.

```
#ifndef FILE_WRITER_H
#define FILE_WRITER_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class File_Writer{

private:
int test;

public:
File_Writer() { }

void create_event_file(void);
void write(const string file_name, string data);
};

#endif // FILE_WRITER_H
```

The cpp file

```
#include "file_writer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

File_Writer::File_Writer(void){
cout << "Object of File_Writer is created" << endl;
}

void File_Writer::create_event_file(void){

ofstream outputFile;

outputFile.open("event.txt");

string data;
cout << "Enter event title : " << endl;
getline(cin,data);
outputFile << textToSave;

cout << "Enter event date : " << endl;
getline(cin,data);
outputFile << textToSave;

cout << "Enter event start time : " << endl;
getline(cin,data);
outputFile << textToSave;

outputFile.close();
}

void File_Writer::write(const string file_name, string data){

ofstream outputFile;

outputFile.open("all.txt");

outputFile << data;

outputFile.close();
}
```

And the main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file_writer.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){

string input;
File_Writer fw;

cout << "Welcome to the event creation program!\n" << endl;
cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
cout << "| event - To create event file   |" << endl;
cout << "| entrants - To create entrants file |" << endl;
cout << "| coursess - To create courses file |" << endl;
cout << "---------------------------\n" << endl;

getline(cin,input);

if(input == "event")
    fw::create_event_file();


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the future it is good to include the line number for your errors. (In this case it was easy, but it will generally help people trying to answer.)

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this, which implies that `fw` is the name of a class or namespace:

```
 fw::create_event_file();
// ^^ This is a "scope opearator"
```

With this, which implies that `fw` is a variable:

```
 fw.create_event_file();
// ^ This is a "member access opearator"
```

Comment: As a little explanation: `::` tries to access a static member of the class, whose type is specified before the `::`. The period accesses a variable.

Comment: @Wald remember that compiler errors will point you to the specific file and line number where the error exists.  You omitted that from your question as if you didn't notice the importance of that.